# Original Estimates in TFS Scrum projects (TFS 2017)

Tags: tfs

When creating a task in a TFS project that was created using the Agile template there is an option to enter an original estimate (See image a).

When creating a task in a project that was created using the Scrum template there is not option to enter original estimate at the task level.

Is there a way to add or turn on this feature.  We use the Fibonacci effort sequence at the PBI/User Story level and make use of velocity, but we need to use original estimates at the task level for accounting purposes.

Reference img a:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Estimate (Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate) field exists in Agile and CMMI process template by default. You need to update the Task work item type definition in Scrum process template and add that custom field yourself:

1. Use [witadmin tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018) to export the Task work item from the team project you want to customize:

`witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ScrumProject /n:task /f:task.xml`

2. Add the custom field between `<FIELDS> </FIELDS>`:

`<FIELD name="Original Estimate" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum" />`

3. Add a section between `<Page Label="Details" LayoutMode="FirstColumnWide"> </Page>`:

`<Section>
  <Group Label="Effort">
    <Control Label="Original Estimate" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" />
   </Group>
</Section>`

4. Import the work item type:

`witadmin importwitd /collection:http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ScrumProject /f:task.xml`

Then you'll see Original Estimate field:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may download [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) and edit work item type definition:

1. Open on VS 2017 **Process Editor->Work Item Types->Open WIT from server**.
2. Find your scrum project and work item type **Task**.
3. Add Original Estimate field to fields section:

> Name=Original Estimate
>
> Reference name=Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate
>
> Data type=Double

4. Add new field to layout section.

You may find a sample in agile or cmmi project.